# How to implement TextArea with line numbers visible in JavaFX?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, textarea

In my application I would like to use multiline text component, which shows line numbers on the left (like most of modern IDE's and text redactors do).

Are there any ready solutions for that? If not, I'd like to get some hints of how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:
https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX

This is an ready to use RichTextArea.